# Add function to module that doesn't have class instance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm using the *requests* module.  I have a number of programs that would like to make a complex check on the results of a *requests.get(url)* call.  I thought perhaps I could add this new function in a class that inherited from some part of *requests*.  But the *get* call is in an *api.py* file that contains just static function definitions, no class declaration.  So I can't figure out what my import or subclass definition should look like (*"class Subclass(requests.api)"* isn't working.)

What I was think of ending up with:

r = requests.get(url)
r.my_check()

Is there a class-oriented way to accomplish this, or should I just write a  function in a separate module of my own, pass it the results of the *requests.get(url)* call and be done with it?

Comment: Thank you for the interesting question. However, it is a little difficult to follow. Please write out what you would like to accomplish as code instead of simply text. With additional clarity, I'm certain you will get the help you need.

Comment: @SteveJ: I was wondering if I could end up with:
`
r = requests.get(url)  
r.my_check()  
`
where my_check is the new function.

Comment: I think you might be over thinking this. Just call `response = requests.get(...)` in your `my_check` function, or call it first and pass the result to your function: `my_check(response)`

Answer (score 0):

Not saying it is a great idea, but ultimately I think you are just trying to dynamically add a method to the Response object?

```
import requests
from requests import Response

def my_method(self):
    print(self.content)

Response.my_method = my_method
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')

r.my_method()
```

**Gives...**

```
b'<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><me
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the general solution to add methods.  I'm used to doing this in .Net (inheriting a class and adding methods).  Reasons why this isn't common in Python?

Answer (score -1):

You can define your own function and attach to `requests` module at run-time.

```
def my_get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    original_get = self.get(args, kwargs)
    # do what you want with the original_get, maybe change it according to your needs, then return the changed response.
    return changed_get

requests.my_get = my_get

# now you can use both of them
requests.get(url) # regular get method
requests.my_get(url) # your own get method
```

Comment: @Ramazon Polat Thanks, but I'm not trying to alter the existing _get_ function, but rather add a new function.  Perhaps my edit to the original post makes this clearer.

Comment: This answer doesn't alter the existing get method, instead adds a new one named `my_get`

Comment: @Ramazon Polat Ah, now I see what you're doing.

Comment: And @Alasdair: thanks both for comments, but I don't want to "hide" the _get_ call inside my function (e.g. there's more than one way to do a _get_ with _requests_).  I'll go with writing a function in a separate module.